# How could I add the containing directory as a prefix to a copied file name?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cp

**The issue:** I have bunch of files split across multiple directories, which all have the same name (input.txt).

**What I am after:** I want to firstly copy all of these to a new directory, while adding the containing directory as a suffux to avoid confusion between them and prevent overwriting. This is the basis of what I am trying to do:

```
cp -nr /foo/bar/*/input.txt /new/path/
```

Where do I go from here?

To respond to the comments below, if my file structure in /old/directory contains folders:

```
/old/directory/1/input.txt
/old/directory/2/input.txt
/old/directory/3/input.txt
```

This is an example of my desired output:
/new/directory/ should contain:

```
1input.txt
2input.txt
3input.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'adding the containing directory as a suffix' by giving example input file names and desired output

Comment: Edited. Am addressing answers now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick and also handle any directories that might have spaces in their names (or any other odd characters).

```
#!/bin/bash

tld=./old/directory
newpath=./new/directory

while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
   tmp="${file#*${tld}/}"
   echo cp "$file" "$newpath/${tmp//\//}"
done < <(find "$tld" -type f -name "input.txt" -print0)
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ tree ./old/directory/
./old/directory/
├── 1
│   └── input.txt
├── 2
│   └── input.txt
└── 3
    ├── 3a
    │   └── input.txt
    └── input.txt

4 directories, 4 files


$ ./mvinput.sh
cp ./old/directory/3/input.txt ./new/directory/3input.txt
cp ./old/directory/3/3a/input.txt ./new/directory/33ainput.txt
cp ./old/directory/1/input.txt ./new/directory/1input.txt
cp ./old/directory/2/input.txt ./new/directory/2input.txt
```

Comment: This is really close to what I was after! This prints the entire path, I want just one level up, how do I do that? If that is too much trouble, this will be fine.

Comment: @bananabenana yes, I just changed the code to reflect this requirement.  See proof of concept

Comment: I couldn't get it to remove the rest of the path, but that's still okay - I am daft. I will process it with regex. Cheers

Comment: @bananabenana I'm not sure what you mean by "remove the rest of the path", but nonetheless I have updated the script to now match your newly updated desired output

Answer (score 0):

Well, the tough news is that there's not an obvious manner of doing this in one line -  not one that isn't nonsensically difficult to understand anyway. There may be a way to do it with rsync, and I'm sure that someone smarter than I could do it in awk, but in my opinion, you're better off making a script, or even writing a custom binary that does this for you.

```
find . -name input.txt | while read line
do
    cp "$line" /new/path/`echo $line | cut -d '/' -f3- | sed 's/\//_/'`
done
```

Note that you'll probably have to change the -f3- part of the cut command in order to select which directory name you want to start your suffix as.

Comment: Not quite? I want to move all the files to the same folder. This appears to copy the entire directory structure to the new location, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Aaah, no I misunderstood - you are correct. I assumed you meant you wanted the whole directory structure. I will edit my answer.

Comment: When I do this, I get the following error: `find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).` Also:
`find: paths must precede expression: `/new/path/input.txt'` and
`find: possible unquoted pattern after predicate `-name'?`

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use an array to save the files, also since `/` is not allowed on file names an alternative is to change it to something else, like say an underscore.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##: Just in case there are no files/directories the * glob will not expand by itself.

shopt -s nullglob 

files=(foo/bar/*/input.txt)

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  new_file=${file//\//_}  ##: Replace all /'s with an _ by Parameter Expansion
  echo cp -v "$file" new/path/"$new_file"
done
```

---

As per OP's request here is the new answer.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

##: Although files=(/old/directory/{1..3}/input.txt)
##: can be a replacement, no need for nullglob

files=(/old/directory/*/input.txt)

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  tmp=${file%[0-9]*}
  new_file=${file#*$tmp}
  echo cp -v "$file" new/path/"${new_file//\//}"
done
```

---

Another option is to split the fields using `/` as the delimiter.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

##: Do not expand a literal glob * if there are no files/directories
shopt -s nullglob

##: Save the whole path and files in an array.
files=(/old/directory/*/input.txt)

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  IFS='/' read -ra path <<< "$file" ##: split via / and save in an array
  tmp=${path[@]:(-2)}  ##: Remain only the last 2, e.g. 1 input.txt
  new_file=${tmp// }   ##: Remove the space, becomes 1input.txt
  echo cp -v "$file" new/path/"$new_file"
done
```

- Remove the `echo` if you think that the output is correct.
- It is easy to understand which directory the file came from just replace the under scores with a `/`

Comment: Okay, this is really close to what I was after! This will print the entire path, I want just one level up, how do I do that?